# List sorted in descending order but searched in default order

Tags: java, collections

I am currently studying for OCP right now, and I have come across a very confusing question. The solution key of the textbook I am reading says that this specific piece of code, sorts in descending order but searches in default order. How is it searched in default order, if it is passed to the Comparator to search in descending order?

[image]

Comment: because you don't pass the comparator to binarySearch?

Comment: And it's bad comparator too.  You should use `Comparator.reverseOrder()`  Subtracting integers will lead to problems when sorting lists that contain values near the min and max of an Integer.

Comment: Tehcnically, the solution they provide will have undefined results as Collections.binarySearch wants the list in ascending order.